# Ubuntu 18.04 : How to play sound before login

Tags: sound, login-screen, gdm

I remember an old time when the login screen played a drum sound before login (actually the dialog-question.ogg from Ubuntu sound theme). I found the sound useful to inform you the system was ready so that you should enter your password.

Is it still possible now with Ubuntu 18.04 and GDM?

Thanks.